# getting issue unable to load cache item while upgrading java 8 to java17 with spring boot 3.2.1

Tags: java, spring-boot, oracle11g, xml-parsing, spring-jdbc

I am upgrading from java 8 to spring boot 3.1.2, java 17. I am able to build the application, but run time getting this error. what are the clues.

[image]

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.newEnhancer(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:121)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:109)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:531)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:308)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:358)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:150)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:771)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:589)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:93)
        at com.jpmc.cib.payments.psfxEmailNotification.processor.EmailNotificationJob.<clinit>(EmailNotificationJob.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:79)
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:105)
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:278)
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:221)
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:174)
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:153)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:73)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.springframework.asm.Item.set(int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)'
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassWriter.newClassItem(ClassWriter.java:1110)
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassWriter.newClass(ClassWriter.java:1131)
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassWriter.visit(ClassWriter.java:669)
        at org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor.visit(ClassVisitor.java:121)
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter.visit(DebuggingClassWriter.java:60)
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.ClassEmitter.begin_class(ClassEmitter.java:83)
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.generateClass(KeyFactory.java:249)
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:312)
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:85)
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:83)
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
        ... 17 more
```

dependency

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.asm</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: What Java version are you using?

Comment: You have different versions in the title and the question itself, which one is it? 3.1.2 or 3.2.1?